# Getting the time the system shut down

Tags: android

Is there any way to save what time the Android device shut down. If for example the phone battery dies, can i save the time the phone shuts off. Then call this time at a later stage, when the phone is back on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` broadcast receiver. In the `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` broadcast receiver you can save the current time to your `SharedPreferences`. For example using `System.currentTimeMillis();` and retrieve it back later.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN

Comment: You need to start the app once, then the receiver should be called.